# Jacobi method in Scilab, what is wrong with my implementation

Tags: scilab

Hy,

I have the below Jacobi method implementation in Scilab, but I receaive errors,

```
   function [x]= Jacobi(A,b)
[n m] = size (A); // determinam marimea matricei A
```

//we check if the matrix is quadratic

```
if n<>m then
    error('Matricea ar trebui sa fie patratica');
    abort;
end
```

we initialize the zeros matrix

```
  x = zeros(n,1) // matrice cu zerouri x = [0, 0 ... 0]

// initializarea variabilelor
Itmax=1000.; //numar maxim de iteratii
eps=0.0000000000000001 // toleranta maxima

nrit=0;
ready=0;
while (ready==0)
    for i=1:n
        s=0
        for j=1:n
            if i<>j then
                s=A(i,j)+x(j);
            end
        end
        y(i)=(1/A(i,i))*(b(i)-s);
    end
 abso = norm(x(1),y(1));
 for i=2:n
     if abso<norm(x(i),y(i)) then
         abso=norm(x(i),y(i));
     end
 end
 nrit=nrit+1;
 if((nrit==Itmax)|(abso<eps))  then
     ready=1;
 end
 x=y;
end
for i=1:n
    disp(y(i),'Rezidurile medii');
end
x
```

What is wrong with it!

Sincerly,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what errors you get and I noticed there are some issues in the implementation as well, but you can use the following code which works fine:

#### Jacobi Alghoritm

```
function [x]= Jacobi(A,b)
[n m] = size (A); // determinam marimea matricei A
if n<>m then
    error('Matricea ar trebui sa fie patratica');
end

// initializarea variabilelor
x = zeros(n,1) // matrice cu zerouri x = [0, 0 ... 0]
Itmax=1000.; //numar maxim de iteratii
eps=0.0000000000000001 // toleranta maxima
nrit=0;
ready=0;

while (ready==0)
    for i=1:n
        s=0
        for j=1:n
            if i<>j then
                s=s+A(i,j)*x(j);
            end
        end
        y(i)=(1/A(i,i))*(b(i)-s);
    end
    abso = abs(x(1)-y(1));
    for i=2:n
        if abso<abs(x(i)-y(i)) then
            abso=abs(x(i)-y(i));
        end
    end
    nrit=nrit+1;
    if((nrit==Itmax)|(abso<eps))  then
        ready=1;
    end
    x=y;
end
```

Let's say you saved this in a file at **~/Jacobi.sci**

#### Usage (in Scilab)

```
-->exec('~/Jacobi.sci', -1)
-->Jacobi([3,-1,-1;-1,3,1;2,1,4],[1,3,7])
 ans  =

    1.  
    1.  
    1.
```